# Prove a triangular matrix is invertable if and only if all diagonal values are non-zero.

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A \in K^{n×n}$ be an (upper) triangular matrix,
so $A = (a_{ij})_{i,j = 1,...,n}$ and $a_{ij} = 0$ for $i > j$.
Then A is invertable exactly then, when all $a_{ii} \neq 0; i = 1, . . . , n$.

I have proven that If A is invertable then all the diagonal elements have to be non-zero like this:

Let A be an invertible Matrix and let one $x_{ii}=0$. Because A is invertible, it represents a bijective linear transformation, so the kernel of T is trivial, which implies linear independence of the columns of the matrix. 
Because A is an upper triangular matrix, its diagonal entries represent a linearly independent set of vectors.
But if one $x_{ii} = 0$, then the set of vectors is no longer linearly independent, which is a contradiction.

My problems are
a) i dont know how to prove the other direction
b) I am unsure as to wether this proof works.

Any help is appreciated :)

P.S.: since we didnt introduce the determinant yet, I am not allowed to just say that the diagonals have to be non-zero, so the determinant is non-zero, so it is invertible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, I think, but your proof leaves a lot to be desired.  "Its diagonal entries represent a linearly independent set of vectors," doesn't make sense.  The diagonal entries are numbers, not vectors.

You want to show that the columns form a basis if and only if the all the diagonal entries are nonzero.  Suppose all the diagonal entries are nonzero,  Then for any vector $Y$, we can solve the equation $AX=Y$, by back-substitution, as usual.  That is, the image of $A$, considered as a linear transformation is the whole space, so the columns form a basis.

Conversely, let $k$ be the smallest index such that $a_{kk}=0$.  Then then $k$th column is in the span of the first $k-1$ columns, and the columns aren't linearly independent.  (If $k=1$, then the first column is $0$ and we are done.)

Comment: Just so im getting this right:

If the diagonals are non-zero i can write the columns as a Basis, since they form linearly independent vectors ifd and only if the diagonals are 0 (since AX=Y can be solved by using the Gauss algorithm)...

and the proof the other way around would be simply that the columns cant be linearly independent if one of the diagonals = 0.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Answer (score 4):

If some $a_{ii}=0$ then the first $i$ columns are all in the subspace spanned by the first $i-1$ basis vector, hence are linearly dependant.

---

If all $a_{ii}$ are nonzero, write
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}B&v\\0&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$
where $B$ is an $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ upper triangular matrix with non-zero diagonal entries. For a proof by induction, we may assume that $B$ is invertible, i.e., $BC=CB=I_{n-1}$ for some $C$.
Observe that
$$\begin{pmatrix}B&v\\0&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}C&w\\0&x\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}I_{n-1}&Bw+xv\\0&xa_{nn}\end{pmatrix}.$$
Can you pick $x\in\Bbb R$ and $w\in\Bbb R^{n-1}$ to make this $I_n$?

Comment: Im a bit confused in order to get the inverse of the leftmost 2x2 matrix shouldnt C and x be 1 and w 0?

or did you mean $x = 1/a_{nn} $ and w = 0?

Comment: @AnotherNoone $x=1/a_{nn}$ is correct as you want $xa_{nn}=1$. But $w=0$ will not work because you want $Bw+xv=0$. Hint: Multiply this equation with $C$ from the left